# PHP regex not returning any matches

Tags: php, regex

First attempt and I think I am very close.

I need to identify this line in a wp-config.php file.

> define('DB_NAME', 'test');

So that is..

> define('DB_NAME', 'ANYTHING');

I came up with this which works in an online regex helper.

```
(define).\'(DB_NAME)\',\s\'(.*?)\'.;
```

However when I plug this into `preg_match` it returns null.

```
preg_match($customdb, '(define).\'(DB_NAME)\',\s\'(.*?)\'.;', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Pattern should be first parameter in preg_match.

Comment: And you need delimiters too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the regex delimiters. Also, the regex comes as the first parameter (as Rikesh noted):

```
preg_match('/(define).\'(DB_NAME)\',\s\'(.*?)\'.;/', $customdb, $matches);
```

Then, the dot matches any character, not just an opening/closing parenthesis. Removing  unnecessary capturing groups, you get:

```
preg_match('/^define\(\'DB_NAME\',\s\'(.*?)\'\);/m', $customdb, $matches);
```

Comment: To be fair, he probably doesn't want `preg_match_all` if he's matching a certain define.. defeats the object if he has more than 1 ;) - cool, +1'd for the edit

Answer (score 4):

You could use this regex which is not bullet proof:

```
preg_match("@define\('DB_NAME', '([^']+)'\);@", $customdb, $matches);
```

In practice, the white-space and quotes could vary.

Comment: Thanks, all blogs on our server are generated by the Wordpress installer so whitespace and quotes should be consistent. Just need a quick way to change the install details when a blog is moved.